# How do I repair / reconfigure a broken Perl package when apt and dpkg both depend on Perl?

Tags: apt, system-installation, dpkg, perl

Recent system updates resulted in errors including this:

```
 debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate Fcntl.pm in @INC 
(you may need to install the Fcntl module))
```

I submitted bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1410324) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1404353)

Now I am unable to install any new software or updates because both APT and `dpkg` depend on Perl which is broken.

Without doing a complete re-install of Ubuntu and all currently installed packages, how can I repair the damaged Perl configuration?

Comment: I know that a system re-install is one fix but want to know how to do this without such a drastic move.

Answer (score 1):

An answer provided to this same question at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263685&p=13220665) suggested using the LiveCD to chroot into the system and re-install Perl. However, using chroot to get into the system does not avoid the dependency of apt and dpkg on Perl.

Currently, the only working solution I have found is to re-install Ubuntu and the desired packages.

Comment: If neither `dpkg` nor `apt-get` works, then using a chroot isn't going to change that.

Comment: @muru, thanks for the comment. I see what you mean. Perhaps the only thing to do is to copy the missing files from the LiveCD to the broken system (assuming the problem is only due to missing files). I'll look into it.

Comment: You might be able to use [`debootstrap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/debootstrap.8) to re-install a basic Ubuntu system from a live CD. That should get `dpkg` and `perl` to a consistent system.

Comment: @muru, would I be correct in saying debootstrap would not enable me to fix the current installation on the same partition without destroying it? Since my goal is to repair the system without having to reinstall the system and all packages, this would not be better than re-installing Ubuntu and packages again in the usual way (e.g. from a LiveCD), correct?

Comment: I'll have to experiment a bit and see. Will update when I can.

Comment: @muru thanks. I have wiki'd the answer to reflect that I included some of your comments in the answer. If you find a solution feel free to post a new answer or edit this one. I will refrain from accepting an answer until one gets some confirmations that it works as I don't have the experience and confidence with Ubuntu yet to test these myself.